# How to create boxes from error bars using Matplotlib's PatchCollection when the x-axis uses datetime object?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib provides an example on "[Creating boxes from error bars using PatchCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/statistics/errorbars_and_boxes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-errorbars-and-boxes-py)".
Following the example there, I would like to implement the `make_error_boxes()` function given in that example to a situation where the x-axis of the graph shows dates (i.e. it uses python's `datetime` objects) instead of integer or float numbers.

How do I amend the `make_error_boxes()` function?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def make_error_boxes( ax, xdata, ydata, xerror, yerror, facecolor='r',
                      edgecolor='None', alpha=0.5 ):

    # Loop over data points; create box from errors at each point
    errorboxes = [Rectangle( (x-xe, y-ye), xe*2, ye*2 )
               for x, y, xe, ye in zip(xdata, ydata, xerror, yerror)]

    # Create patch collection with specified colour/alpha
    pc = PatchCollection(errorboxes, facecolor=facecolor, alpha=alpha,
                         edgecolor=edgecolor)

    # Add collection to axes
    ax.add_collection(pc)


fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1,1 )
days = np.arange( 10 )
dates = [ datetime.today() + timedelta( days=day.tolist() ) for day in days ]
y = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8 ] 
xerr = [timedelta( days=0.5 ) for day in days] #TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
#xerr = [ 1 for day in days] #TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
yerr = [3.75, 1.7, 2.5, .5, 1.1, 1.5, 3., 2., 1., .5]
ax.errorbar( dates, y, yerr=yerr,label='Median')

make_error_boxes( ax, dates, y, xerr, yerr ) 
                  
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Use Matplotlib dates**

Python's `datetime` object needs to be [converted to Matplotlib dates](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html?highlight=date2num#matplotlib-date-format), which uses floating-point numbers to specify the number of days. This conversion can be done using the [matplotlib.dates.date2num()](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html?highlight=date2num#matplotlib.dates.date2num) function. The magnitude of 1 day appears to be 1.0.

**2. Use matplotlib.dates date tick locators and formatters to show the Matplotlib dates.**

**3. Revised Script:**

My script should be revised to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

def make_error_boxes( ax, xdata, ydata, xerror, yerror, facecolor='r',
                      edgecolor='None', alpha=0.5 ):

    # Loop over data points; create box from errors at each point
    errorboxes = [ Rectangle( (x-xe, y-ye), xe*2, ye*2 )
                   for x, y, xe, ye in zip(xdata, ydata, xerror, yerror) ]

    # Create patch collection with specified colour/alpha
    pc = PatchCollection(errorboxes, facecolor=facecolor, alpha=alpha,
                         edgecolor=edgecolor)

    # Add collection to axes
    ax.add_collection(pc)


fig, ax = plt.subplots( 1,1 )
days = np.arange( 10 )
dates = [ datetime.today() + timedelta( days=day.tolist() ) for day in days ]
mpdates = [ mdates.date2num(date) for date in dates ]
y = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8 ] 
xhalfmag = ( mpdates[1] -mpdates[0] ) * 0.5
xerr = [ xhalfmag for _ in mpdates]
yerr = [3.75, 1.7, 2.5, .5, 1.1, 1.5, 3., 2., 1., .5]

ax.errorbar( mpdates, y, yerr=yerr, label='Median' )
make_error_boxes( ax, mpdates, y, xerr, yerr )

fig.autofmt_xdate() # rotate and align the tick labels so they look better. From https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator( mdates.WeekdayLocator( byweekday=(MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU), interval=1, tz=None ) )
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( mdates.DateFormatter("%b %d %a", tz=None) )
                  
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]